# laravel array sort by

Tags: arrays, laravel

data comes in fine. what i want to do is to sort the sizes sort by key 'size_piece' from smallest to largest. can you help me

Controller code;

```
foreach ($cco as $order_item){
        foreach ($order_item->orderPiece as $piece_item){

            $order_piece += $piece_item->piece;

            $cut_order['cutting_piece'][$order_item->collectionColor->color_name]['size_piece'][$piece_item->CollectionColorSizeBarcode->size] = $piece_item->piece;
            $cut_order['cutting_piece'][$order_item->collectionColor->color_name]['total_piece'] += $piece_item->piece;

        }

        $cut_order['order'][$order_item->id] = $order_item;
        $cut_order['order'][$order_item->id]['total_piece'] = $order_piece;

        $order_piece = 0;
    }

 return dd($cut_order);
```

Screen output like this;

[image]

Comment: hi onur! welcome to stackoverflow. it would be easier if you could share the input array that `$cco` and the expected output. also, if you can help it, avoid using screenshot (especially for code, json, xml, anything textual).

Comment: also check [laravel helper](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-array-sort) documentation. it has numerous tools you can use.

Comment: ``ksort($cut_order['cutting_piece'][$order_item->collectionColor->color_name]['size_piece']);`` before ``$cut_order['order'][$order_item->id] = $order_item;`` should work.

Answer (score 0):

If it there is no way to sort them before insertion.

The solution is to map your array:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
 
$mapped = Arr::map($cut_order['cutting_piece'], function ($value, $key) {
    return Arr::set($value, 'size_piece', Arr::sort(Arr::get($value, 'size_piece', []));
});

$cut_order['cutting_piece'] = $mapped;
```

Documentation : [Laravel Helper Array Map](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-array-map)

Comment: this code. When I run it it gives an error like this "Method Illuminate\Support\Arr::map does not exist."